# Is it possible to make children of dispay:none element to be visible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list that has `dispaly:none` but I want under certain conditions to make a child element of the list (`li`) visible. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: you can clone the elements and append to another visible element, even a temporarily created one which can be simply destroyed later using `remove()`. This is pretty much how most tooltip plugins work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. If your container is invisible then visibility of its children is irrelevant. So in your case you have to hide all `li` elements you want to be non-visible, but list as such have to be visible.